# Why does more threads occur slower algorithm in Kepler GK107?

Tags: c++, cuda

well, I have an GeForce 740m GPU so it is the GK107 architecture 2xSMX, 64 MaxWarps/MP, 32 Threads/Warp. So I should be able to run 2x64x32 = 4096 threads in one time, am I right?

Well I'm running on my notebook the gSLIC algorithm (Segmentation to superpixels).

Firstly I started with an image of size 640x480 and I was segmenting the image to 1200 superpixels. After the calculations the kernel was called with 1200 blocks and 256 threads per block, the result was about 95ms.

Then I improve the size of the block, but the calculation gives me the same amount of blocks and threads per block, 1200 and 256. The only difference was, that the algorithm allocated an extra unnecessary memory in the shared memory and the result was about 200ms. Can it be caused because of the extra memory allocation or it can be something else?

I would like to ask you some questions about the processing these threads.

1. So I have 1200 blocks and 256 threads per block what is 307200 threads, but I can't run them all at the same time only 4096, am I right?
2. Max warps per mp is 64 and each warp is 32 threads, my block size is now 256, so that's mean one block is like 256/32 = 8 warps, then on one SMX I can run at the same time 64/8 = 8 blocks in the same time, am I right?
3. Does CUDA start to process the whole block or it can just start to process 32threads from a block of size 256? For example if I have two 256 threads block and 8 warps, is it possible that the cuda will take 128 threads from both blocks or it will always take firstly one whole block if possible?!

Or I'm understanding the thread processing wrongly.

Comment: There are too many questions in here. Try to be more precise and one question means one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answers to my questions.

The problem was that the shared memory was occupied.
As I said in my question, in both scenarios the kernel was executed with 1200 blocks and 256 threads per block, the only difference was in the amount of shared memory allocation.

In the first scenario I set the MAX_BLOCK_SIZE to 256. The kernel runs with 1200 blocks and 256 threads per block, in the kernel I allocated two arrays, the calculations are the following 9*4B*256 = 9216B = **9kB per one block**. The shared memory is 48kB, that's mean I can run on one SMX only 48 / 9 = 5 blocks, what is 5*256 = **1280 threads.**

In the second scenario I set the MAX_BLOCK_SIZE to 1024. The kernel runs with 1200 blocks and 256 threads per block again(because of the image size and number of segments), but in the kernel I allocated a bigger arrays now. 9*4B*1024 = **36kB per block**. In this case I can run only 48 / 36 = 1 block per SMX, what is **256 threads.**

1. YES, the SMX unit can have at most 64 warps or 16 blocks allocated at time. Due to resource limitations (blocks, warps, registers per thread, shared memory per block, or barriers) the number may be less.
2. I'm not sure, but probably yes, but maybe the wraps can be selected from different blocks, so even in this scenario there can be even 16 blocks per SMX.
3. Maybe, as I wrote it in 2.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about your problem statement, but typically, when more threads cause something to happen longer, it can mean a couple of things:

- You have too many threads. It only benefits to have as many threads as cores available.
- If you don't have too many threads, it means your threads are contending for data too much.

Data contention can happen in two ways (perhaps more).

- The more obvious is that literally the data is being shared, and the forcing of mutually exclusive access to the data is expensive.
- The less obvious is that cache lines are being shared amongst threads, and the data in the cache lines happen to be located close to each other. When various threads modify the data, other threads have to be "notified" unnecessarily of the changes in cache due to the fact that they are interested in data in the same cache line. The solution for this problem is to try and localize data used by a thread, and only modify the "main memory" once the parallel stuff is done.

Another reason for threads slowing things down might be cache misses. This means that data is cached, but when retrieval time comes, the data is not around any more (due to cache line being used by other thread). The idea is to try and keep data that change together in the same cache line.

This can be done by:

- changing one's data access patterns to row access instead of column
  access,
- by using data structures that aren't node based (as their access patterns are not localized to specific memory.
- Pad with alignment fields/bytes.
- Test.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't help me because I forgot to focus more detailed to the source of the problem. So it is my fault, but I've found the answer.

Comment: "You have too many threads. It only benefits to have as many threads as cores available" - this is not really true in the context of CUDA cores. This answer seems to be aimed at CPU programming, rather than GPU.